# Django user authentication working properly EXCEPT 1 view/template

Tags: python, django, jinja2, django-socialauth

I am working with Django 1.11.5 and logging-in and validating users via Social Auth.

The user authentication, log-in and logoff are working as expected in 12/13 of my templates. All my templates extend my navbar and footer base.html template.

In 'base.html' I have the following code for the navbar:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li class="nav-item">
<span class="nav-link" id="user-name">{{ request.user.username }}</span>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logoff</a>
</li>
{% else %}
<li class="nav-item log-in-link">
<a class="btn btn-primary nav-link log-in" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"><span>Log-In <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
</li>
{% endif %}
```

Now, this navbar code works properly in 12/13 of my templates. It is only for 1 template/view/URL where the user is not authenticated.

I have tried debugging by printing out the user name and information in the template giving me errors but it looks like the user is getting logged out when reaching that template via its URL and view.

I am totally lost.

Could someone point out things I can check/do to debug and locate the source of this logoff error? I can provide the relevant code if needed.

**views.py code**

```
def details_request(request, request_data_ID):

data_request_object = DatasetRequest.objects.get(pk=request_data_ID)

user_ID = data_request_object.user.username

has_attributes = False
request_data_attrs = []
if len(data_request_object.attr_names) > 0:
    if len(data_request_object.attr_names['names']) > 0:
        has_attributes = True
        for idx, attr_names in enumerate(data_request_object.attr_names['names']):
            request_data_attrs.append([attr_names,
                                       data_request_object.attr_names['descriptions'][idx],
                                       data_request_object.attr_names['types'][idx]])
data_request_detail_template = {
    'dataset_request_title': data_request_object.dataset_title,
    'dataset_request_description': data_request_object.dataset_description,
    'dataset_votes': data_request_object.dataset_votes,
    'dataset_date': data_request_object.created_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    'request_data_ID': request_data_ID,
    'has_attributes': has_attributes,
    'request_attrs': request_data_attrs,
    'user': user_ID,
    'is_completed': data_request_object.is_completed
}

data_comment_object = Comments.objects.filter(request_dataset_FK=data_request_object).order_by("-comment_votes")

if len(data_comment_object) > 0:
    comment_list = []
    for comment_object in data_comment_object:
        if comment_object.isComment:
            comment_list.append([comment_object.comment, comment_object.created_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), comment_object.comment_votes, comment_object.pk, comment_object.user.username])
    data_request_detail_template['comments'] = comment_list

return render(request, "detail_requests.html", data_request_detail_template)
```

Comment: probably it makes sense to show us code of your view.  You can also try another templates with current view and this template with another view to find out if the problem is in view or template

Comment: Thanks I will add the view code and try your debug method

Comment: Ok so using {% if not user.is_anonymous %} as stated in [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829447/django-user-authentication-not-working worked for authenticating the user in my template but it still does NOT update the 'base.html' navbar code I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying:

```
user_ID = data_request_object.user.username
```

and put it into context under `user` key.

In template you have {% if user.is_authenticated %} which means that you are trying to access missing attribute `is_authenticated` of `user.username` which always evaluates to False.